# finding article by date code in google search appliance GSA

Tags: datetime, google-search-appliance

The Google Search Appliance goes through and finds out the date of each article when it crawls (last modified date is the default).

However, it doesn't turn up articles when you query by date code.

Is there any way to get the GSA to do this?

(We have a daily broadcast which people often search for by date code. Right now we have to manually put in the 4 most common date codes into the meta-keywords in order for them to be pulled up through a query)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using inmeta:date as described in the Search Protocol Reference documentation?

Alternatively, if the date code is in the document content or the URL you could use entity recognition to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make sure GSA is collecting the document date is to check the search results in XML format and see if  tag has the date value. You can see the results in XML format by removing any proxystylesheet parameter in the URL.

If the value of  tag is empty then GSA is not getting the document dates.

You can configure the document dates under Crawl and Index > Document Dates (at least at GSA version 7). We are using a meta tag approach. We put a date meta tag to each document/page and tell GSA to use this meta tag to sort the documents. The full list of options are:

- URL
- Meta Tag
- Title
- Body
- Last Modified

Here are some links that helped me to find answers when dealing with a similar problem:

https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2675414?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/64/xml_reference#request_sort_by_date

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-search-appliance-help/sort$20by$20date$20not$20working